# Getting wrong constructor name in my nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I have the following code

```js
class asdError extends Error {
  constructor(message) {
    super(message)
    this.name = 'asdError'
    
    Error.captureStackTrace(this, this.constructor)
  }
}

try {
  throw new asdError('asd')
} catch(error) {
  console.log(error.constructor.name)
}
```

If I run it by it self, like doing `node ${filename}.js` I get the expected constructor name: `asdError`. But when I run it in my web app I get `Error` as constructor.

My app was scaffolded using `angular-fullstack generator` and I run it using `gulp serve`.

If you need me to provide more information please tell me and I will do my best to provide it.

Comment: Your code is probably made ES5 compatible, where `Error` is not actually extended.

Comment: When I run this in Node 8 I get 'asdError' on the console.

Comment: I ran it on node lts (6) and it worked. its the fact that something is screwing up my code like babel or something. I am going insane trying to find out who is responsible,

Comment: @FranciscoFarías Extending `Error` is not supported in pre-ES6 environments, and cannot be polyfilled.

Comment: Yup. I now understand. I can, however change the constructor reference in the constructor (I know this is a workaround and its wrong in many levels but I make what I can with what Im given)

Comment: There are few npm packages that address Error inheritance in ES5.

Comment: I ended up telling Babel to ignore the file and using require instead of import